# How to follow anchor tag / external link with cucumber and capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, capybara, bdd

```
When(/^I click the "(.*?)" link$/) do |subscribe|
  click_on subscribe 
end
```

the subscribe link goes to an external website:

```
https://www.somesite.com/path/to/something?this=that
```

however when I run the feature I get this error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/path/to/something" (ActionController::RoutingError)
```

**How do I get capybara to follow this external link and not ignore the query?**

Answer (score 1):

Cucumber and Capybara unfortunately don't work with external links.  I would recommend using Capybara-Mechanize: https://github.com/jeroenvandijk/capybara-mechanize

Try this (although only works with one link):

```
When(/^I click the "(.*?)" link$/) do
  Capybara.current_driver = :mechanize
  visit 'https://www.somesite.com/path/to/something?this=that'
end
```

Here is some examples of its use:
http://turriate.com/articles/2011/feb/testing-twitter-oauth-with-real-data/